# How to color geom_bar by y-axis values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a standard bar plot with ggplot2 geom_bar. I'm trying to fill the bars with the highest values with a different color than the bars with the lowest values.

For example,

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl) )) + geom_bar()
```

How can you color bars above 20 in red (e.g., E), bars from 10 to 20 in blue (B and D), and bars below 10 in orange (A and C).

Thanks for any insights!

[image]

I'm using geom_col and my actual code looks like this

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=State, y=Value)) +
 geom_col()
```

Comment: I've added one, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use `cut`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = cut(stat(count), breaks = c(0, 8, 12, Inf)))) +
  labs(fill = "Breaks")
```

[image]

You obviously need to adjust the breaks according to your needs / data.

---

**edit**

If we use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar` we need to change `fill = stat(count)` to `fill = value_column` (whatever the `value_column` is but it should be the same as the one we mapped to `y`).

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(trt = c("a", "b", "c"), outcome = c(2.3, 1.9, 3.2))
ggplot(df, aes(trt, outcome)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = cut(outcome, breaks = c(0, 2, 3, Inf)))) +
  labs(fill = "Breaks")
```

Comment: Typo: *You might use `cat`*.

Comment: Thanks @RuiBarradas. Edited.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work for me. I'm actually using geom_col.

Comment: Thank you! I had an unrelated bug before.